# Make a .png to a textureRegion in Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

Im tring to to make png to textureRegions and after some search im confused. Some  say i have to use texture,others textureAtlas,others bitmapTextureAtlas and so on.
So could anyone tell me how to do it, from creating what has to be created, to having the textuReregion usable everywhere i need it.
Im absolutely confuse so please be detailed! Thanks.

Texture constructor

```
a = new ITexture() {
            @Override
            public int getWidth() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public int getHeight() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public int getHardwareTextureID() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLoadedToHardware() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void setNotLoadedToHardware() {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean isUpdateOnHardwareNeeded() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void setUpdateOnHardwareNeeded(boolean pUpdateOnHardwareNeeded) {

            }

            @Override
            public void load() {

            }

            @Override
            public void load(GLState pGLState) throws IOException {

            }

            @Override
            public void unload() {

            }

            @Override
            public void unload(GLState pGLState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void loadToHardware(GLState pGLState) throws IOException {

            }

            @Override
            public void unloadFromHardware(GLState pGLState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void reloadToHardware(GLState pGLState) throws IOException {

            }

            @Override
            public void bind(GLState pGLState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void bind(GLState pGLState, int pGLActiveTexture) {

            }

            @Override
            public PixelFormat getPixelFormat() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public TextureOptions getTextureOptions() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasTextureStateListener() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public ITextureStateListener getTextureStateListener() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void setTextureStateListener(ITextureStateListener pTextureStateListener) {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step:

1. In your project "assests" folder you may create "gfx" folder.
2. Put your example.png image in your "gfx" folder. Name has to be lowercase.
3. Coding. It is good idea to have some ResourceManager class with methods that load your textures. Lets say you create one. In one of them (ie `loadExamplePNG()`:

   - `BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");` - this sets defoult folder for your images (you dont have to use it, but then you will have to put path to image later)
   - `BitmapTextureAtlas exampleTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(),
     256, 256);` - texture atlas is like a sheet of paper with stickers on it. You create big atlas to put your images/textures and load them together. The numbers 256, 256 say how big is your atlas. They have to be power of two (256, 512, 1024, 2048). Some phones cannot go more than 1024 x 1024.
   - `ITextureRegion exampleTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
     exampleTextureAtlas, activity, "example.png", 0, 0);`- here we put our image on the atlas like sticker on the paper. You choose your image "example.png" and put it on `exampleTextureAtlas` in the position (0, 0). You may put more than one region in the atlas but you cannot choose same coordinates. So if first region is in the position (0, 0) and it is 100x100 big - second image have to be for example in position (110, 0) so they do not overlap).
   - `exampleTextureAtlas.load();` - and in the end we load our atlas. Simple.

Aslo, as @mayurN pointed: if you put this code in the method of resourceManager (made as singleton pattern class) you use it as:

`ResourceManager.getInstance().loadExamplePNG();`

Comment: also i noticed that it can be done by creating an ITexture from an image(in gfx) and then creating a new TextureRegion with ITexture and some parameters, this lets you cut a piece of the ITexture. Or this shouldnt be done?And how do i make it a TiledTextureRegion?

Comment: It is possible solution: Here you can find some tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/12065/how-to-create-a-simple-android-game I find my approach easier.

Comment: The second point, what is activity, The Current CLASS? Because i cant find that method

Comment: it is your MainGameActivity extending BaseGameActivity or SimpleBaseGameActivity. If you are creating your scene in your main activity, just put there "this", if you are creating your scene as a separate class, you need to pass the activity as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand clearly what your problem is, but if you want to load your .png image, this is the way to do it.

```
BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

AddTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(),
    256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
Add_region = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
    AddTextureAtlas, activity, "add.png", 0, 0);
AddTextureAtlas.load();
```

and you attach it like this

```
Sprite mySprite = new Sprite(0, 0,
    ResourcesManager.getInstance().Add_region,
    ResourcesManager.getInstance().vbom);
attachChild(mySprite);
```

I am using a separate Resources manager class to load textures. Where gfx is a folder in assets

Comment: My problem is that i dont know how to make an atlas, put image in it or use them. And i dont have no Add_region or AddTextureAtlas class.

Comment: Check this step by step tutorial and tell me whether your problem is solved. http://andenginefromscratch.blogspot.in/2011/03/introduccion-andengine-parte-ii.html

Comment: i belive is an older version, for example my texture constructor is different

Comment: Post some of your texture constructor code if possible, then it will become  clear where your problem is.